# Save string in C preprocessor

Tags: preprocessor

We have following macros:

```
#define START(x) [...]
#define FOO(x, a, b, c) [...]
#define BAR(x, a, b, c) [...]
#define END(x) [...]
```

We have piece of code:

```
START(foobar)
FOO  (foobar, 1, 2, 3)
FOO  (foobar, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
BAR  (foobar, 2, 3, 4)
END  (foobar)
```

Can we do something to let START store *foobar* somewhere? To xform previous into:

```
START(foobar)
FOO  (1, 2, 3)
FOO  (0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
BAR  (2, 3, 4)
END  ()
```

(something like `#define FOO(x) #define VAR x`)

Comment: btw, a solution would be to create a global variable, set it in START and utilize it in the FOO/BAR/END macros

Answer (score 2):

What about:

definition:

```
#define START() [...VAR...]
#define FOO(a, b, c) [...VAR...]
#define BAR(a, b, c) [...VAR...]
#define END() [...VAR...]
```

usage:

```
#define VAR foobar
START()
FOO  (1, 2, 3)
FOO  (0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
BAR  (2, 3, 4)
END  ()
#undef VAR
```